# Apache or WAMP for a PHP beginner?

Tags: php

As I am a beginner in the PHP programming field, I would like to know if Apache or Wampserver suits my skill? Anybody please give a good option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apache is a server, Wamp is a package of Apache, MySQL and PHP. Ok, you need wamp.

Answer (score 3):

WAMP stands for **W**-indows (as the OS), **A**-pache (as the webserver), **M**-ySql(the database), **P**-HP (the scripting language). So you see, its the same. you'll end up using Apache webserver only.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on a lot of factors but since you mentioned Wamp then I will assume you have a Windows OS.

WAMP is the Windows OS as the operating system, Apache as the webserver , MySQL as the data store and PHP as an included component.

Any would suit your skill, as both include the Apache web server.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say if it suits your skill. Depends on the extensions you need.

With only an apache server you don't have everything. If you're a PHP programmer you at least need the PHP extension for Apache.

WAMP stands for Windows Apache Mysql PHP and, as it already says, has PHP (and MySQL) included. In most cases it is sufficient to do the basic programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of them they both will work perfectly fine and easy to use. Although I have always used xampp (with no specific reason but it is very easy to use).

Answer (score 0):

WAMP contains Apache so you will use it either way. It really depends how much work you want to do to get started.

To install Apache, PHP, MySQL (or other database), etc individually takes more time and there is a step by step process you need to follow.

On the other hand, installing WAMP is quick and easy (simply download and launch the install package), which caters to more novice users.  From there you can choose which extensions you want to use and enable them.

I would use WAMP as a beginner to simplify things